# Querying SQL Database returned an error: Login failed for user 'Free Trial

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-stream-analytics, azure-sql-server

so currently I am doing a connection from Azure IoT Hub - Data Stream Analytic - SQL Database. and when I wanted to test the output connection that I have declared in Stream Analytics Job, suddenly error popped-up "Querying SQL Database returned an error: Login failed for user 'Free Trial"[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cx6kS.jpg). Please help me I already checked the firewall and everything is okay.
Thanks! :)

Comment: is there any code? what have you tried already? is this really a programming question?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Falco, I am new in microsoft azure. there is just a query. I have created the Iot hub, sql database, device provisioning service, sql server, stream analytics job and also the connection of all steps. But still error popped-up "Querying SQL Database returned an error: Login failed for user 'Free Trial" when I tested my output.But when I start the stream analytics job, it started successfully. Is it because I use free trial?

Comment: Hi, can you double check that the credential you used are working. For example, you can go to the Azure SQL DB you created and navigate to the query editor and see if you can log in and make some queries. More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-connect-query-portal

Answer (score 0):

Please go to Azure Portal, search for Azure SQL Database (https://portal.azure.com/#blade/HubsExtension/Resources/resourceType/Microsoft.Sql%2Fservers%2Fdatabases), make a click on your database. On the subscription column to your right hand you may read a hyperlink with a text like "(Disabled) Free Trial". If you click on that text, you may get a description like "This account is on a deprecated billing system. Ask the Account Admin, @, to contact Support to move it to the new system.".

Please update your credit card information (validate it) or upgrade your subscription to pay-as-you-go or another type of subscription.